# Poner una cadena de texto a un valor

Tags: datagrid, angular-material, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy realizando una app web dónde tengo que ponerle la cadena de texto ''pzs'' a un valor que me arroja desde la base...

Intento con cellTemplate, pero no me sale...
<dxi-column dataField="cantidad" caption="Cantidad" alignment="center" cellTemplate="dateCell" dataType="string" [width]="80">
<dxo-header-filter [allowSearch]="true">
<div *dxTemplate="let cellData of 'dateCell'">
{{cellData.value | : 'pzs'}}

Entonces, quiero que salga CANTIDAD + pzs.

[image: resultado de mi código...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas utilizar cellTemplate="dateCell" si solo estás tratando de agregar "pzs" a la salida. Además, no necesitas un pipe para esto.

```
<dxi-column dataField="cantidad" caption="Cantidad" alignment="center" dataType="string" [width]="80">
  <dxo-header-filter [allowSearch]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
  <div *dxTemplate="let cellData of 'content'">
    {{cellData.value}} pzs
  </div>
</dxi-column>
```